# Unable to OAuth with account that owns YouTube channel

Tags: oauth, google-api, youtube-api

I have a google account that I was previously uploading videos to using the v2 YouTube API. This account I guess has two accounts linked to it, because when I go through OAuth flows I have to choose which account.

The 1st account, the one I setup the API in developer console, gives me the option to authorize YouTube API controls.
The 2nd account, the one that actually is the YouTube channel, only says that I'm giving my application offline access, there is no permissions specified relating to YouTube.

I did my OAuth using the 1st account, since that one actually listed youtube permissions. Got my refresh token and added it to the application. However, when I go to attempt to insert a video to YouTube I get the following error:
Code 401 Unauthorized: youtubeSignupRequired

It's as though I'm not linking at all to the YouTube channel account even though they are both on the same Google account.

Has anyone encountered this before?
By the way, I know with certainty that my API calls work properly, as we were able to upload from the dev environment. The dev account is only a single account though that owns the channel on the same account as the API.

Comment: You need to link the YouTube account and the Google account; https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/errors explains a bit more.

Comment: @jlmcdonald I looked into this and it seems like my YouTube account is already linked with the Google account. When I attempt to goto http://youtube.com/gaia_link after logging into the Google account I get an error page saying "Please sign in as your personal identity."

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this.

It turned out I needed to do the OAuth with the 2nd account, the one for the YouTube channel. Despite it not requesting any permissions related to YouTube and only getting offline access, I was able to successfully upload using the refresh token I received.

Definitely a case of the most illogical solution being the correct one.